# Qlik Sense IfNum combined with If Statement

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am attempting to run a an AVG on a Column where a number exists and that number is greater than 0, the column has mixed data, most fields will have a number but a few credit results come back NA or DNR.

The following expression, checks out as OK but doesn't return any values. I know the AVG expression works correctly as I have used it on clean data. I believe the error is coming from the IsNum

```
=if(IsNum(Credit) = '-1', Avg({< [Credit] = {"<>0"} >} [Credit]), (Credit))
```

Comment: is the `r` tag needed?

Comment: Yeah, why the r tag?

Answer (score 1):

Probably is better to create additional column, in your script, indicating if the `Credit` value is number or not.

`if( isNum(Credit), 1, 0 ) as isNumberCredit`

After this your expression became simple.

`avg( {< isNumberCredit = {1} >} Credit )`

OR

`avg( Credit * isNumberCredit )`

Using this approach will decrease the performance in bigger data sets.

Comment: Where would I load the if statement?

Comment: in the load script when the data is loaded

Comment: Thats what I tried but retuned a bunch of errors
`The following error occurred:
Unexpected token: ',', expected one of: ')', 'OPERATOR_PLUS', 'OPERATOR_MINUS', 'OPERATOR_MULTIPLICATION', 'OPERATOR_DIVISION', 'OPERATOR_STRING_CONCAT', 'like', ...
The error occurred here:
if( isNum(Credit)>>>>>>,<<<<<< 1, 0 ) as isNumberCredit`

Comment: `if( isNum(Credit) = -1, 1, 0 ) as isNumberCredit` if you try this?

Comment: I got it to work with the first suggestion, I had to add `Load` to the top of the script selection in the Data Load Editor.  It seems successful, but the rest of the dashboard now says `Incomplete Visualization'